# Android: SQLiteDatabase - no such column

Tags: android, sqlite

I am trying to study and make a simple database that creates one table with only one row. I first see that it works when I used 'update()' method of SQLiteHelper. However, when I try it with SQL command 'UPDATE...SET', it throws an error that 'no such column'

I have no idea why I can't use 'UPDATE...SET' command since 'update' method has no problem. If anyone knows android SQL well, would you please help me? Below is my code and error message.

**CODE:**

```
public class TestDBMain extends Activity {
private final String SETTINGS_TABLE_NAME = "settings";

// Columns
private final String DEV_ID = "dev_id";
private final String SERVER_NAME = "server_name";
private final String SERVER_PORT = "server_port";
private final String SERVER_SUBFOLDER = "server_subfolder";
private final String USERNAME = "username";
private final String PASSWORD = "password";

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);

    DB_Settings db_s = new DB_Settings(this);
    db_s.deleteDBSettings();
    db_s.addDBSettings(SERVER_NAME, "test_server_01");
    // ERROR occurs here
    db_s.addDBSettingsWithSQLCommand(SERVER_NAME, "test_server_22");
}

public class DB_Settings extends SQLiteOpenHelper {
    private static final String DB_NAME = "settings.db";
    private static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 1;
    private String[] Settings_FROM = { _ID, DEV_ID, SERVER_NAME, SERVER_PORT, SERVER_SUBFOLDER, 
            USERNAME, PASSWORD};

    private Context mContext;

    public DB_Settings(Context context) {
        super(context, DB_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);
        mContext = context;
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
        db.execSQL("CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS "+SETTINGS_TABLE_NAME+"("+_ID+" INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, "
                +DEV_ID+" VARCHAR,"
                +SERVER_NAME+" VARCHAR,"
                +SERVER_PORT+" INTEGER,"
                +SERVER_SUBFOLDER+" VARCHAR,"
                +USERNAME+" VARCHAR,"
                +PASSWORD+" VARCHAR);");        

        initialize(db);
    }

    @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {

    }

    public void deleteDBSettings(){
        mContext.deleteDatabase(DB_NAME);
    }

    private void initialize(SQLiteDatabase db){
        ContentValues values = new ContentValues();

        values.put(DEV_ID, "1");
        values.put(SERVER_NAME, "1");
        values.put(SERVER_PORT, 443);
        values.put(SERVER_SUBFOLDER, "1");
        values.put(USERNAME, "1");
        values.put(PASSWORD, "1");

        db.insertOrThrow(SETTINGS_TABLE_NAME, null, values);
    }

    public void addDBSettings(String key, Object value){
        // Insert a new record
        SQLiteDatabase db = getWritableDatabase();
        ContentValues table_value = new ContentValues();

        if(value.getClass().equals(String.class)){
            table_value.put(key, value.toString());
        }
        else if (value.getClass().equals(Integer.class)){
            table_value.put(key, (Integer)value);
        }

        // add to database
        db.update(SETTINGS_TABLE_NAME, table_value, "_id=1", null);
    }

    public void addDBSettingsWithSQLCommand(String key, Object value){
        SQLiteDatabase db = getWritableDatabase();
        db.execSQL("UPDATE "+SETTINGS_TABLE_NAME
                +" set "+key+" = "+value.toString()
                +" where _id = 1;");
    }
 }
```

**Error Log:**

```
07-20 01:00:53.516: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(6066): Caused by: android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: no such column: test_server_22: UPDATE settings set server_name = test_server_22 where _id = 1;
07-20 01:00:53.516: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(6066):     at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.native_execSQL(Native Method)
07-20 01:00:53.516: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(6066):     at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.execSQL(SQLiteDatabase.java:1727)
07-20 01:00:53.516: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(6066):     at android.test.db.TestDBMain$DB_Settings.addDBSettingsWithSQLCommand(TestDBMain.java:109)
07-20 01:00:53.516: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(6066):     at android.test.db.TestDBMain.onCreate(TestDBMain.java:35)
07-20 01:00:53.516: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(6066):     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1047)
07-20 01:00:53.516: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(6066):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2627)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this query for update..

```
 db.execSQL("UPDATE "+SETTINGS_TABLE_NAME
                +" set "+key+" = \""+value.toString()
                +"\" where _id = 1;");
```

Comment: Nice to see you again, CapDroid. It worked! If you don't mind, would you teach me how come these two backward slash fixed the problem?

Comment: actually value must be in double inverted cooma (") and we can't use directly it(") in java so need to slash (\) before it(") i hope you getting all..

Answer (score 4):

For querying string you have to put ' and '.Try this

```
db.execSQL("UPDATE "+SETTINGS_TABLE_NAME
                +" set "+key+" = '"+value.toString()
                +"' where _id = 1;");
```

Comment: This one works, too! Thank you for your answer and explanation. Since Capdroid helped me first I'll pick his answer but give your answer +1 vote. Thank you!